# Can't load Keras model with Custom objects trained on Kaggle TPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, kaggle, tpu

I have trained my model with

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.layers import concatenate, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
os.environ["SM_FRAMEWORK"] = "tf.keras"
import segmentation_models as sm

def jaccard_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_flatten = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_flatten = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_flatten * y_pred_flatten)
    final_coef_value = (intersection + 1.0) / (K.sum(y_true_flatten) + K.sum(y_pred_flatten) - intersection + 1.0)
    return final_coef_value

def multi_unet_model(n_classes=7, image_height=512, image_width=512, image_channels=3):
    inputs = Input((image_height, image_width, image_channels))
    source_input = inputs

    c1 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(source_input)
    c1 = Dropout(0.2)(c1)
    c1 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c1)

    c2 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(p1)
    c2 = Dropout(0.2)(c2)
    c2 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c2)

    c3 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(p2)
    c3 = Dropout(0.2)(c3)
    c3 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c3)

    c4 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(p3)
    c4 = Dropout(0.2)(c4)
    c4 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c4)

    c5 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(p4)
    c5 = Dropout(0.2)(c5)
    c5 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c5)

    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4], axis=3)
    c6 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(u6)
    c6 = Dropout(0.2)(c6)
    c6 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c6)

    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3], axis=3)
    c7 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(u7)
    c7 = Dropout(0.2)(c7)
    c7 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c7)

    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2], axis=3)
    c8 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(u8)
    c8 = Dropout(0.2)(c8)
    c8 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c8)

    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
    c9 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(u9)
    c9 = Dropout(0.2)(c9)
    c9 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c9)

    outputs = Conv2D(n_classes, (1,1), activation="softmax")(c9)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    return model

# Percentages of data for each class
class_percentages = {
    'urban_land': 7.8383,
    'agriculture_land': 5.6154,
    'rangeland': 9.6087,
    'forest_land': 1.2616,
    'water': 2.9373,
    'barren_land': 1.0828,
    'unknown': 0.00017716
}

# Calculate the inverse of percentages
inverse_percentages = {cls: 1 / pct for cls, pct in class_percentages.items()}

# Normalize weights
sum_inverse_percentages = sum(inverse_percentages.values())
weights = [weight / sum_inverse_percentages for cls, weight in inverse_percentages.items()]

print("Class Weights:", weights)

# Loss function
dice_loss = sm.losses.DiceLoss(class_weights=weights)
focal_loss = sm.losses.CategoricalFocalLoss()
total_loss = dice_loss + (1 * focal_loss)

# Metrics
metrics = ["accuracy", jaccard_coef]

with strategy.scope():
    # Build the model
    model = multi_unet_model()

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    
    # Compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=total_loss, metrics=metrics)

# Print model summary
model.summary()

train_size = int(len(dataset)*0.8)
train_dataset = dataset.take(train_size)
val_dataset = dataset.skip(train_size)

train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size=16)
train_dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(train_dataset)

val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size=16)
val_dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(val_dataset)

history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                    validation_data=val_dataset,
                    epochs=3,
                   )
```

then I saved model with

```py
with strategy.scope():    
    model.save("new_3_epoch_model.h5")
```

and when I load the model with

```py
load_model("/kaggle/working/data/imgs/new_3_epoch_model.h5", custom_objects={"dice_loss_plus_1focal_loss": total_loss, "jaccard_coef":jaccard_coef})
```

it shows this error:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[46], line 1
----> 1 load_model("/kaggle/working/data/imgs/new_3_epoch_model.h5", custom_objects={"dice_loss_plus_1focal_loss": total_loss, "jaccard_coef":jaccard_coef})

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_api.py:183, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    176     return saving_lib.load_model(
    177         filepath,
    178         custom_objects=custom_objects,
    179         compile=compile,
    180         safe_mode=safe_mode,
    181     )
    182 if str(filepath).endswith((".h5", ".hdf5")):
--> 183     return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath)
    184 elif str(filepath).endswith(".keras"):
    185     raise ValueError(
    186         f"File not found: filepath={filepath}. "
    187         "Please ensure the file is an accessible `.keras` "
    188         "zip file."
    189     )

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/legacy/saving/legacy_h5_format.py:155, in load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    151 training_config = json_utils.decode(training_config)
    153 # Compile model.
    154 model.compile(
--> 155     **saving_utils.compile_args_from_training_config(
    156         training_config, custom_objects
    157     )
    158 )
    159 saving_utils.try_build_compiled_arguments(model)
    161 # Set optimizer weights.

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/legacy/saving/saving_utils.py:145, in compile_args_from_training_config(training_config, custom_objects)
    143     loss = _deserialize_nested_config(losses.deserialize, loss_config)
    144     # Ensure backwards compatibility for losses in legacy H5 files
--> 145     loss = _resolve_compile_arguments_compat(loss, loss_config, losses)
    147 # Recover metrics.
    148 metrics = None

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/legacy/saving/saving_utils.py:245, in _resolve_compile_arguments_compat(obj, obj_config, module)
    237 """Resolves backwards compatiblity issues with training config arguments.
    238 
    239 This helper function accepts built-in Keras modules such as optimizers,
   (...)
    242 this does nothing.
    243 """
    244 if isinstance(obj, str) and obj not in module.ALL_OBJECTS_DICT:
--> 245     obj = module.get(obj_config["config"]["name"])
    246 return obj

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```